# delphi passing running parameters to other instance via wm_copydata gives wrong result in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, wm-copydata

This code used to work with Delphi 5, but with delphi XE2 does not work as expected. The string passed using wm_copydata will be cut.

```
procedure SendAppParameters(aMsgStr: string);
var
  hwnd: THandle;
  cds: CopyDataStruct;
begin


  hwnd := FindWindow('TMyAppFormMain', nil); //<-- Substitute window classname with your own
  if hwnd <> 0 then
  begin
   // showmessage(aMsgStr);
    // prepare the data to copy
    cds.dwData := 0;
    cds.cbData := length(AMsgStr);
    cds.lpData := PChar(AMsgStr);
    // activate the destination window
    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
    // send the data to the first instance using a wm_CopyData message
    SendMessage(hwnd, wm_CopyData, Application.Handle, integer(@cds));
  end

end;
```

And in the Main Form I have:

```
procedure TMyAppFormMain.GotMessage_CopyData(var Msg: TWmCopyData);
var
  MsgString: string;
  I: Integer;
begin

  MsgString := PChar(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData);
  showmessage(MsgString);


end;
```

Comment: The `cbData` member of the `COPYDATASTRUCT` structure is a size in bytes, so you need to set there `Length(AMsgStr) * SizeOf(Char)` since from Delphi 2009, chars are 2 bytes in size.

Comment: thanks that solved it, and also I replaced integer(@cds)) with LPARAM(@cds).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact your code has never been correct. It is broken even on ANSI versions of Delphi.

Let's take a look. You prepare the message like this:

```
cds.cbData := length(AMsgStr);
cds.lpData := PChar(AMsgStr);
```

On an ANSI Delphi that means that the text is marshalled up to but not including the null-terminator.

The receiver does this:

```
MsgString := PChar(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData);
```

This relies on there being a null-terminator present. There's no reason to expect that there would be and even to attempt to read beyond `cds.cbData` bytes is an error.

The recipient must take care to heed the value of `cds.cbData` that is sent and not read beyond the end of the buffer.

Now, the other issue is that you have moved to a Unicode Delphi and so text is now UTF-16 encoded.

To send the text I would write:

```
cds.cbData := length(AMsgStr)*SizeOf(Char);
cds.lpData := PChar(AMsgStr);
```

And on the receiving side it should be:

```
SetString(MsgString, PChar(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData), 
  Msg.CopyDataStruct.cbData div SizeOf(Char));
```

The cast that you use, `integer(@cds)`, is incorrect. That should be `LPARAM(@cds)`.

Comment: If you use `SizeOf(Char)` on the sender then you should use `div SizeOf(Char)` on the receiver to match.

Comment: well it was not my code, it just some code I copied and pasted, since I never dig a lot into lower level things unless it is necessary. I see now that even the receiving part had an error, in that it is assuming the null terminated string. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: This is why it's important not to copy code without checking it.